# SQL Server: how min and max blank the other row if they same result and convert 24 hours to 12 hours without where method

Tags: sql-server

I want the join EmpID to EmployeeNo and combine the last name, first name, and middle name from the second table and I want to the entries separate the O and I with min and max but if they don't have a min or max become blank or null I just want to become blank the certain row because if they don't blank the row the result is the same.

This is the 1st

```
| Entries               | recordDate              | Empid  | Reference |             
+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------+-----------+  
| 0016930507201907:35I  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
| 0016930507201917:06O  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
| 0016930507201907:35I  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
|                       | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |
```

2nd table

```
| LastName | FirstName | middleName | EmployeeNO |
+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Cruz     | Kimberly  | Castillo   |   001693   |
```

I want to join that two table with the second table combine the lastname,FirstName, and middleName . the employeeNo join to Empid but the entries would be separate between I and O with min or max of certain empId but if the entries have not I or O it would be blank like this and also with where

```
| Name                    | EmployeeNO | RecordDate              | TimeIn | TimeOut | 
+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------+---------+
| CRUZ, MA  KIMBERLY, CA  |    001693  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 |  07:35 |  05:06  |
| CRUZ, MA  KIMBERLY,CA   |    001693  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 |  07:35 |
```

If I have a where there have a error please help me this is the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: can you please post your query as well

Comment: Select B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ',' + B.MiddleName[Name] ,A.[RecordDate],B.[EmployeeNO]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, CAST( SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS TIME), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeIn], 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, CAST(SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS TIME), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeOut]   
   FROM Employees  [B]
   inner JOIN [DTR Upload] [A] 
   ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID
   this is the continue of the code

Comment: GROUP by B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName,B.[EmployeeNO], A.[recordDate]
   order by A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName + ','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName asc

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it for you. I use a couple of nested CTEs. The first one doe your data conversions, the second one sets the min and max times, and the final query sets any rows that have missing I records to blank.

The test data uses table variables for your Table1 and Table2.

```
declare @E table(Entries varchar(50), RecordDate varchar(50), EmpID varchar(6), Ref int)
insert @e values ('0016930507201907:35I','2019-05-07 00:00:00 000','001693',1693)  
,('0016930507201917:06O','2019-05-07 00:00:00 000','001693',1693)  
,('0016930507201907:35I','2019-05-08 00:00:00 000','001693',1693)
,('','2019-05-08 00:00:00 000','001693',1693)

declare @B table(LastName varchar(50),FirstName varchar(50),middleName varchar(50),EmployeeNO varchar(6))
insert @B values ('Cruz','Kimberly','Castillo','001693')

;with e as (
select right(Entries,1) as InOut, 
    convert(datetime,left(recorddate,10)) as RecordDate, Entries,
    substring(Entries,15,5) as t,
    EmpID 
from @e
where len(ltrim(Entries))>0
)
, details as (
select B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ',' + B.MiddleName [Name], 
    EmployeeNO,
    RecordDate,
    min(case when InOut='I' then T else '99:99' end) as I,
    max(case when InOut='O' then T else '' end) as O
from @B B
join e on e.EmpID=B.EmployeeNO
group by B.LastName,B.FirstName,B.MiddleName,EmployeeNO,RecordDate
)
select Name, EmployeeNO, RecordDate, case when I='99:99' then '' else I end as TimeIn, O as TimeOut
from details
```

Comment: this is great but i want to display all data please help me

Comment: Do you mean other columns? Just add them to the column lists (and the group by if required), joins etc. This is an example of how to do it, you should be able to add the rest. There is not enough information in your question to show any more.

Comment: how please give me a example

Comment: Not without giving a hint as to what "all the data" means. I have displayed all the data that is shown in your question.

Comment: the data in the above is example only i have so many data that i can display because i remove the where method to display of my all data but i have a error  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
".

Comment: As you will see the answer I have does not get the error. So I would look at modifying your's to match my conversions.

Comment: the code that i try is in the above please take a look sorry for inconvenience

Comment: You can see in the first part of my query - the CTE called "e" where I do date conversion and extract the time. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: what about the conversion of the time(24 hours to 12 hours)

Comment: Convert it from string to time and then format it however you want. Your example was 24Hr time.